# Access datasource in eventhandlers

Tags: eclipse, function, report, birt, eventhandler

The below code is generating errors:

Initialize:

```
 var firstC = ["AUD","ZAR"];
var secondC= ["AUD","BRL","CAD","USD"];


function colorG(item, col, row){

var currency = firstC[col] + "-"+ secondC[row];
if(verifyCurrency(currency)==true)

item.getStyle().backgroundColor="green";
}

function verifyCurrency(currency)
{

if(this.getRowData().getExpressionValue("row[digital]").indexOf(currency)!=-1)
return true;
else return false;
}
```

cell:

```
colorG(this,1,0);
```

**In which phase do I have to place verifyCurrency so that it will work?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption about "this" in your verifyCurrency function is wrong. I don't know Javascript good enough to tell you more about this, but I think that "this" is always defined inside a function. But it is not pointing to your item instance!

To fix this (no pun intended), pass the item as an argument to your verifyColor function.

Comment: After i changed to item instance, the cell gets color even if condition is not met.
Do you understand why?

Comment: I found my error. it was in addition to your answer.thanks for helping!!!!